# Calculate the (average) time a product is in stock

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

I'm trying to calculate the time a product is in our stockroom. I accomplished sofar a calculation of the amount of days between the 'restocked_date' and the 'shipment_date'.

This looks fine. I used the following code:

```
tijd in magazijn = IF( OR(voorraad[restocked_date] <= voorraad[shipment_date], voorraad[shipment_date] > 2021-06-30), DATEDIFF(voorraad[restocked_date], voorraad[shipment_date], DAY), DATEDIFF(voorraad[restocked_date], TODAY(),DAY))
```

Now I want this to be the average. Which I also accomplished by using this code:

```
Gemiddelde in magazijn per EAN = AVERAGEX( KEEPFILTERS(VALUES('voorraad'[EAN])), CALCULATE(AVERAGE('voorraad'[tijd in magazijn])))
```

The part that's making this difficult for me, is:
I want the average just to be calculated over the items which have a 'restocked_date' of 1 july 2021 or later. So in the example there should be an average of 40 (rounded from 39,5) instead of 26.

[image: spreadsheet showing all input]

When I get rid of all the specifics in a row, my average comes up with this so far:

[image: the average with only EAN in the table]

This is the result when using the solution given by Ryan B. Unfortunately not what I'm looking for.

[image: The outcome with the solution from Ryan B.]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have modified my first attempt at a solution.  Before I claimed that the AverageX wasn't needed, but it seems clear that I was wrong.

But I am sure that you need your average to be filtered to just those rows with restocked date > 1 july 2021, and you haven't got that expressed in your DAX yet.  So here's another way you might try to get that result:

```
Gemiddelde in magazijn per EAN =
AVERAGEX (
    KEEPFILTERS ( VALUES ( 'voorraad'[EAN] ) ),
    CALCULATE (
        AVERAGE ( 'voorraad'[tijd in magazijn] ),
        FILTER ( 'voorraad', 'voorraad'[restocked_date] >= DATE ( 2021, 7, 1 ) )
    )
)
```

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't give me the wanted average. I don't know where this doesn't work, but my former sollution worked a little more in the direction I'm looking for. Except for the average I want: 158 divided by 4 as the average, instead of 158 divided by 6 (which it does with my own code).

Comment: I'm trying to get in an image of the result from your code, but don't know how to. So I've put it in the original question...

Comment: I made one more attempt at this based on your feedback -- I edited my response with the changes.

Comment: Thanks! Great work. This did the trick.

Any chance of getting the "tijd in magazijn" also calculated only from 1 july 2021? ;-)
I tried another measurement by using "switch" but I don't seem to get it working.